# Multiple document types in crystal report

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

i try to fetch multiple doc types in crystal report.. If doc type is CN then amount in - and if amount doc type is DN then it must be + ... .
i want like this

```
crystal report
no. doctype docno  docdate customer exempteddate S.Tax Rate S.t Amount
1   CI      12   01-01-2016  ABC                  150  20%  15200*
1   CN      12   01-01-2016  abc                  -32  20%  1234*
```

this is what i tried

```
crystal report
no. doctype docno  docdate customer exempteddate S.Tax Rate S.t Amount
1   CI      12   01-01-2016  ABC                  150  20%  15200*
```

- whatever the amount is i write rough amount

query ...i paste specific line

```
and acdochdr.doctype='CN', 'DN' ,'CI'
```

any solution?

Comment: its realling confusing....if you don't write what do you need. You told you tried something but what is that you are unable to achieve? post sample output what you require

Comment: i already write .. check line " i want like this "

Comment: Ok what is the problem with the code that you have tried